# validation on postback if gridview is empty

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to provide an ok cancel popup 'if' the gridview has no rows and I thought this would work like a client script, but when I hit ok the control skips rest of the method. Is there anyway I could perform this validation or alert and move the control to the next statement?

```
protected void btnRunD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       try
        {
            int iESStatus = 0;
            int iRunStatus = 0;
            ApplicationUser au = (ApplicationUser)Session["ApplicationUser"];
            if (UploadFileGrid.Rows.Count <= 0)
            {
               ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(),     "err_msg", "confirm('No new data files have been uploaded. Are you sure you want to run EYDS Processing Module?');",
           //true);
            }

            if (au.RoleID != 2) //RoleID is not Admin!
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "err_msg", "alert('You do not have enough privileges to use this functionality!');",
           true);
           }
           else
           {.........}
}
```

The part I'm having difficulty with is here:
I am trying to provide an ok cancel popup 'if' the gridview has no rows

```
if (UploadFileGrid.Rows.Count <= 0)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "err_msg", "confirm('No new data files have been uploaded. Are you sure you want to run?');",       
    }
```

Comment: You can do this using javascript function without postback then is there any specific need for calling javascript function on postback?

Comment: show more code. What exactly you need to execute on `Ok` button click?

Comment: @Piya How exactly can I check if my gridview is empty in javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing your button is something like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDoSomething" runat="server" Text="Do Something" OnClientClick="return GetConfirmation();"  OnClick="btnDoSomething_Click" />
```

then add a javascript function as below:

```
function GetConfirmation() {
    var rowscount = document.getElementByID(<%=UploadFileGrid.ClientID%>).rows.length;
    return rowscount > 0 || confirm('No new data files have been uploaded. Are you sure you want to run?');
}
```

then it'll be postbacked just when the user press ok when confirm button is shown.

Comment: +1 In my opinion `return rowscount > 0 || confirm('No new data files have been uploaded. Are you sure you want to run?');` looks better

Comment: @Aravindh, don't think there will be any issue with update panel, give it a go!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using javascript or jquery:

```
$("#<%=btnApprove.ClientID %>").click(function () {
            if ($("#<%=UploadFileGrid.ClientID %> ").find("tr").length == 0) {
                if (confirm('No new data files have been uploaded. Are you sure you want to run?')) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

        });
```

and when user press OK,your page will be postbacked,you can write the code which you want to execute after that.
I hope this code will help you.